# Inserting elements within an array, with decrementing pointer?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, merge

Essentially, I'm trying to merge two sorted lists together, into one list. Im attempting to do this efficiently as possible.
Im attempting to replace the zeros with the second list of numbers, and sort them as well. Im trying to merge in reverse, for time complexity sake. Unfortunately, after the first insert statement `nums1.insert(j,nums2[-1])`, the element (6) is getting inserted into the second to last index, rather than the last index (pointer j). I visualized the code and this is what I saw. My expected output, (albeit I'm editing the array in place and not returning anything)  is `nums1 = [1,2,2,3,5,6]`. The array must stay the same capacity, and can't be temporary. I feel maybe I'm implementing the insertion incorrectly. I can append the value, and that fixed the problem on the first iteration, however I can append within the middle of the array, after pointer j is decreased. Thanks for any help/advice!

```
def merge():

    nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0]
    m = 3
    nums2 = [2,5,6]
    n = 3
    i=m-1
    j=-1
        
    while nums2:
        #last element of nums1 and nums2 compared
        if nums1[i]<=nums2[-1]:
            #last element of list 2 is larger than last element of list 1
            nums1.pop(j)
            nums1.insert(j,nums2[-1])
            # pop the last value off of nums2
            nums2.pop()
            j-=1
    
            
        #last element of nums1 and nums2 compared    
        if nums1[i]>=nums2[-1]:
            #last element of list 2 is larger than last element of list 1
            nums1.insert(j,nums1[i])
            #pop off the value at current index, and replace it with the last element of nums2
            nums1.pop(i)
            nums1.insert(i,nums2[-1])
            #pop the last value off of nums2
            nums2.pop()
            j-=1
i+=1
merge()
```

Comment: Why not just replace all the zeros with values from `nums2` and then sort in place with `nums1.sort()` ?

Comment: @Avandale its a practice interview question, I'm trying to be as formal as possible, if yah know what I mean. They usually want you to code out everything, and not use a bunch of built in methods.

Comment: @NightBeezy - I doubt they expect you to reinvent the wheel. Simply do `sorted(nums1+nums2)`. Inbuilt methods should be more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def merge(n1,m,n2,n):
    k=m+n
    nn=n-1
    mm=m-1
    for i in range(k-1,-1,-1):
        if mm>=0 and nn>=0:
            if n1[mm]<n2[nn]:
                n1[i]=n2[nn]
                nn-=1
            else:
                n1[i]=n1[mm]
                mm-=1
        elif mm>=0:
            n1[i]=n1[mm]
            mm=-1
        else :
            n1[i]=n2[nn]
            nn-=1
    print(n1)
        




nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0]
m = 3
nums2 = [2,5,6]
n = 3
merge(nums1,m,nums2,n)
```

Comment: This solution is definitely correct, is there anyway you could help me understand what you did? Id really appreciate it.

Comment: for i in range(k-1,-1,-1): this will iterate with the pointer from end to start and mm,nn are the pointers of nums1 and nums2 ,by using pointer we compare the values and by using assignment operation we assingn the highest value to the nums1